# Most efficient memory type for kdb+

Tags: kdb, kbd-rdb

I am currently configuring a server that will run a kdb+ tickerplant with several subscription processes. Is there an optimal physical memory type for realtime kdb data?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the type sizes at http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/#datatypes
Answer depends on what you mean by "efficient" - by the far the largest hit you take in latency is memory allocation, so the less you have to allocate the better. That means smaller types.

But of course you have to weigh that up against your use cases.

For your realtime always make sure the tickerplant inserts the time column so that `#s` is maintained on the time column for efficient querying.

The tickerplant itself publishes on a timer - the longer the timer the less hit on cpu, but then the tp is collecting data for a while before publishing. Again, weigh up against use cases. BTW make sure your tickerplant is writing the log file to a fast local disk so as to decrease pub delay and iowait.

If you're operating high load from multiple sources, consider OS tweaks too like tcp quickack ( http://www.techrepublic.com/article/take-advantage-of-tcp-ip-options-to-optimize-data-transmission/). There's similar tweaks for memory allocation and disk i/o.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have edited my post to clarify *physical* memory type. There are many options on the market.

Comment: oh i see. As far as I know there aren't any benchmarks against memory types aside from stacresearch's M3 stack.